# Iterate through specific column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file I need to process in a python script. I've chosen to use the `pandas` module.

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Name,Private IP
bastion001,10.238.2.166
logicmonitor001,10.238.2.52
logicmonitor002,10.238.2.53
```

And I want to iterate through the `Name` column.

I am reading the file like this:

```
hosts_list = os.path.join('..', '..', 'source_files', 'aws_hosts_list', 'aws_hosts_list.csv')
fields = ['Name']
df = pd.read_csv(hosts_list, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
```

When I print the entire data frame I see this:

`print(f"This is the DF: \n{df}")`

```
This is the DF:
                      Name
0               bastion001
1          logicmonitor001
2          logicmonitor002
```

But when I try to iterate through the output this is what I see:

```
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    print(f"{i} {j}")
```

---

```
0 Name    bastion001
Name: 0, dtype: object
1 Name    logicmonitor001
Name: 1, dtype: object
2 Name    logicmonitor02
```

How can I just print the names from the `Name` column so that I can have a list that looks like this:

```
bastion001
logicmonitor001
logicmonitor0002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(list(df['Name']))
```

Output:

```
['bastion001', 'logicmonitor001', 'logicmonitor002']
```

If you want them one per line, try this:

```
for val in list(df['Name']):
    print(val)
```

Output:

```
bastion001
logicmonitor001
logicmonitor002
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list, you can do this:

```
list_names = df['Name'].tolist()
print(list_names)

['bastion001', 'logicmonitor001', 'logicmonitor002']
```